# Can I create freemium chip-based poker software without licence?

Tags: software

I want to create poker software which will let players play with chips not real money, however they will be able to buy more chips if they wish to do so.

Do I need to hold gambling licence for such thing? (UK)

Comment: not familiar with UK laws but you want to consult a tax consultant office for what you really need for opening such a business.

Comment: This definitely seems more of a legal question than a poker question, and I'm guessing that each country and/or state will have its own requirements here.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can create such software, that is only a technical problem. Search over at stack overflow and you will find questions and answers related to poker shuffling routines and such. I am assuming you have some technical experience to take on such a challenge.

With the question about licensing, I really can not tell you. It is a very complicated question that requires a professional answer. Anytime you mix poker with money your going to face some kind of legal challenge just about anywhere. If you are going to set up a online presence with a poker game were chips for the game can be purchased that is playing for money. So if your plan is to do something like that, consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

To be defined as gambling, I think among other things you need to be able to win something of value back. If the players chips are forever locked up then this might tip the scales in your favour. Checking the legal agreements for other play money Poker apps like Zynga's should also give you a hint.

Of course you are also going to need a lawyer to vet this for you.